# JAXB unmarshall XML and get all the recognised tags

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there a way to retrieve all the recognized tags from the content tree returned after unmarshaling a xml with JAXB

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = getJaxbContext(p.getName()).createUnmarshaller();

    unmarshaller.setSchema(getJaxbSchema(p.getName(), getJaxbContext(p.getName())));
//p is the JAXB package

    Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(in); // the input stream of xml

    if(o instanceof JAXBElement){
        o = ((JAXBElement)o).getValue();
    }
```

For example if the xml seen below was the input stream i would like to get a list of strings like this ["parentTag","childTag1","childTag2","childTag3"]

```
<parentTag>
  <childTag1>
    <childTag2>
    </childTag2>
  </childTag1>
  <childTag3/>
</parentTag>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName("*")`

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {
     // Get element
     Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
     // element.getNodeName() is the tag name
}
```